# For some reason my program is not reading the file that I asked to be read

Tags: vb.net, csv

You can see thatt I've opened the file just below, but I've recently discovered that It is reading a file open above, which I have closed.

```
    Dim TestNO As Integer
    Dim myLines As New List(Of String)
    Dim sb As StringBuilder

    FileOpen(10, "F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\testtests.csv", OpenMode.Input)

    Dim Item() As String = Split(fullline, ",")
    Dim MaxVal As Integer = Integer.MaxValue

    Do Until EOF(10)
        fullline = LineInput(10)

        If Item(7) > MaxVal Then
            MaxVal = Item(7)
            TestNO = MaxVal
        End If
    Loop
```

This is where I open and close my previous file.

```
Dim flag As Boolean = False

FileOpen(1, "F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls\stdnt&staffdtls.csv",
             OpenMode.Input)

    Do Until EOF(1)
        fullline = LineInput(1)

        Dim item() As String = Split(fullline, ",")

        If enteredusername = item(0) And enteredpassword = item(1) Then

            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.Clear()
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome," & item(3) & item(4))

            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            Console.Clear()
            flag = True

            If item(2) = "p" Then
                FileClose(1)
                pupilmenu()
            ElseIf item(2) = "s" Then
                FileClose(1)
                staffmenu()
            ElseIf item(2) = "a" Then
                FileClose(1)
                adminmenu()
```

Comment: VBA and VB.NET **are not** the same thing.  It looks like you're using VB.NET with a mix of legacy VB syntax.

Comment: Vb.Net, sorry about that.

Comment: I only see one file opened in your code.  I'd also suggest using VB.NET equivalents for the various items like `FileOpen`.

Comment: The other file is opened above in the code.

Comment: Tim, any suggestions?

Comment: What I'm ultimately trying to achieve is reading the highest number in the array(7)

Comment: What does your input file look like?  And post the part of your code where you open and close the previous file.

Comment: I know, very cowboy'ish.

Comment: I would suggest you use the System.IO namespace to open/read files.

Answer (score 0):

`FileOpen`, `EOF`, and `LineInput` are all old VB6-style methods which are provided primarily for backwards compatibility.  It would be far preferable to use the new .NET classes provided in the `System.IO` namespace.  For instance, this same task is easily performed line this:

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls\stdnt&staffdtls.csv")
    Dim fields() As String = line.Split(","c)
    If (enteredUserName = fields(0)) And (enteredPassword = fields(1)) Then
        ' ...
    End If
Next
```

Notice that I also used `line.Split` rather than `Split(line)`, which is also an old VB6-style method.  It's better to use the new `String.Split` method.

The `File.ReadAllLines` method opens the file, reads the entire contents of the file, closes the file, and then returns all of the data as an array of strings, with each item in the array being one line from the file.  This is a very simple way to read an entire file.  If it is a particularly large file, however, it would be better to use a `FileStream` object to read one line at a time.

Also, it's worth mentioning that reading a CSV file yourself can be complicated.  They aren't always as simple as simply splitting on commas.  For instance, the following is an example of a valid CSV line:

```
Bill, "Red, White, and Blue", Smith
```

As you can see, that line only contains three fields, but it contains four commas.  Also, the quotation marks should not be considered as part of the value in the second field.  The easiest way to read a CSV file is to use the `TextFieldParser` class, which handles all of those eccentricities.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been using some of this System.IO stuff few times, but I'm finding it lengthy getting my head round it. Additionally, my code is fairly dated since my teacher is OLD...

Comment: @user3038164 Hey, now... Watch it!  Some people might consider me old too! :)

Comment: Fair enough.  :)  That's apparently so.  Do your best to learn what you can from him.  Technologies change, but principles of good design do not.

Comment: I defiantly will do Steve.

Comment: By the way, how do I close the file? Syntax.

Comment: @user3038164 If you use `File.ReadAllLines`, it closes the file automatically before returning the data.  If you are using a `FileStream`, it would be typically best to enclose it in a `Using` block so that it gets closed automatically when leaving that block.

Comment: Sorry for asking all of these questions. But, how do you identify arrays in a way that a selected field could be read, lets say field (7)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  `fields(7)` would indeed get the value of the eighth item in the array, provided there were that many items in the array, of course.

Comment: I'm just not sure what you are asking.  What about `Item(7)`?  That accesses the eighth item in the `Item` array.

Comment: It's okay, I've just made a little mistake. And, how can I use "For Each" to act as a linear search. Since I need it to read through item(0) and item(1) and concur if they are identical to the users input.